# Javascript Compound Interest Issue

Tags: javascript, formula, calculator

Hoping for some guidance! I'm pulling my hairout!

I'm currently working on the logic for a Compound interest calculator. The user will be able to enter a starting deposit, months they wish to save for, Monthly deposits and select their AER percent (which is applied once a year).

I'm using this formula:

Compound interest for starting deposit:  `P(1+r/n)(nt)`

Future value of a series of deposits: 
`Starting Deposit × {[(1 + r/n)(nt) - 1] / (r/n)}`

I'm just running into a problem with my calculations:

https://jsfiddle.net/3xz8pu9k/21/

The total of the compound for the deposit + monthly instalments should be much higher then the current result.

They should return as shown: 
[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6gBb.png)

If anyone can spot a problem and guide me in the right direction, that would be ace!

Thanks,

Ross

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/articles/investing/020614/learn-simple-and-compound-interest.asp

Comment: Hi Mark, there should be a link to my code on jsfiddle along with a screenshot of the expected result in the original post.

Comment: You calculate the installment as yearly not monthly.  Installment period should be 3*12 not 3. Also adjust the interest to 1.5/12

Comment: Hi Jules, Updating the period to 3*12 and updating the interest  is still shooting me over the expected amount? can you spot anything else that may of been missed?

Comment: I updated your calculator https://jsfiddle.net/3xz8pu9k/37/ Note that this is in arrear calculation where as your expected result is in advance. This is an excel formula for in advance FV(1.5/1200,36,200,300,1) which match your expected result.  change the last parameter to 0 fo in arrear.

Comment: Hi Jules, Thanks for that! I'm really confused about what I'm meant to change to move the calculation over to Advanced rather then in arrear to meet my expected results? - Thanks again!

Comment: Refer to the formula appendix on this excellent hp calculator :) https://www.calcsplus.com.au/site/DefaultSite/filesystem/documents/datasheets/HP12cp_1.pdf

Comment: I modified the jsfiddle with in advance calculation, https://jsfiddle.net/3xz8pu9k/39/.  Refer to this link as it is easier to understand https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/finance/compound-interest-formula.php?page=2